# javascript - Is there a way to grab these values with php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this JS code which works by using the `onclick` method and opens an image in a new window which is the exact size of the image.

I adapted it from the BolGallery script. but the bolGallery script parses this in PHP and is able to get the the 'title','width' and 'height' values dynamically. and also the 'ImageFile' value.

My question is, is there a way to get these with php?

Im not very knowledgeable with JS

```
function GalleryPopup(imageFile, width, height, title){

    var html = '<title>' + title + ' - Click to close </title><body leftmargin=0 topmargin=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 onclick=\"javascript:window.close()\"><img src=\"' + imageFile + '\" alt=\"Click to close\"></body>';
    var popup = window.open(imageFile, '_blank', 'width=' + width+ ', height=' + height + ', status=no');
    popup.document.write(html);
    popup.focus();
}
```

alternatively, if you know of any other ways to achieve what i'm going for then feel free to tell me.

For Instance i dont know what to set the variable like:

```
$imagetitle =
```

Would that work?

i also have jQuery..

Comment: Where is the title being stored? Database, text file, or something? There's a way to use `new Image` to load a file in JavaScript and wait for it to load, then you can just check its `.width` and `.height` properties, but it's pretty fragile, in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jQuery you can get size of image with:

```
$('img').width();
$('img').height();
```

// this is used to grab the source file and title:

```
$('img').attr('src');
$('img').attr('title');
```

Comment: Oh, heck. I didn't know the full-size image with the title was already on the page. I assumed you were clicking on a thumbnail or something.

Comment: i see, so: `var imageHeight = $('img').height(); ` ??

Comment: What do you want PHP to achieve for you? You want it to generate code of the newly opened page?